# How to Combine or Merge Object Array with Object Array Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an object like this in my console:

```
ObjectName1 : Array(3)
0 : { id : 1, name : 'foo' },
1 : { id : 2, name : 'foo-2' },
2 : { id : 3, name : 'foo-3' },

ObjectName2 : Array(3)
0 : { id : 1, foo : 'bar' },
1 : { id : 2, foo-2 : 'bar-2' },
2 : { id : 3, foo-3 : 'bar-3' },
```

and as usually if we want to get the name, just write : `ObjectName1[key].name` right ?

now if i want to get the `key` from `ObjectName2` (foo, foo-2, foo-3) how to get the `key` from `ObjectName2` using the `value` from `ObjectName1` ?

i have written like this :

```
// just say there is an each above this comment
     var name = ObjectName1[key].name;
     var bar  = ObjectName2[key]+"."+name;
// end each
```

but it just showed

> [Object object].foo
>
> [Object object].foo-2
>
> [Object object].foo-3

the output should be like this :

```
bar
bar-2
bar-3
```

it is possible doing like i want to do ? help me please if it is possible

any help will be very appreciated.

*note : i'm not sure what is the case name in my problem, so forgive me if the title went wrong

thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do (or how you're doing it) without seeing a more complete example of your code, but it sounds like you need to use `Object.keys()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but i want the output is `bar`, `bar-2`, `bar-3`

Comment: The structure quoted is highly suspect, and the question unclear. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: @Rajesh but i have already use `$.each` , if i used one more looping, result is duplicate

Comment: @Rajesh you mean `ObjectName2[key.name]` ? because i want to get the `ObjectName2` value using name value from `ObjectName1`

Comment: @DarkCode999 I have added an answer. Hope that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Loop through each object in `ObjectName1` object and get the name in appropriate index, this name will be the key for the ObjectName2 object. Then use that key to print the appropriate value from `ObjectName2`

```js
var ObjectName1 = [{'id' : 1, 'name' : 'foo'}, {'id' : 2, 'name' : 'foo-2'}, {'id' : 3, 'name' : 'foo-3'}];
var ObjectName2 = [{'id' : 1, 'foo' : 'bar'}, {'id' : 2, 'foo-2' : 'bar-2'}, {'id' : 3, 'foo-3' : 'bar-3'}];
for(var i = 0; i < ObjectName2.length; i++){
    console.log(ObjectName2[i][ObjectName1[i]['name']]);
}
```

Comment: well, this is an answer i was looking for, i just need this : `ObjectName2[i][ObjectName1[i]['name']]` because your code exactly like i was write.

thanks for your help sir, you save my day :D

Answer (score 0):

> now if i want to get the key from `ObjectName2` (foo, foo-2, foo-3) how to get the key from `ObjectName2` using the value from `ObjectName1` ?

**If** you know those are parallel arrays (where `[0]` in one array is intentionally a match for `[0]` in the other array), you can simply loop through:

```
ObjectName1.forEach(function(entry1, index) {
    var value = ObjectName2[index][entry1.name];
    console.log(entry1.name + " = " + value);
});
```

Example:

```js
var ObjectName1 = [
{ id : 1, name : 'foo' },
{ id : 2, name : 'foo-2' },
{ id : 3, name : 'foo-3' }
];

var ObjectName2 = [
{ id : 1, "foo" : 'bar' },
{ id : 2, "foo-2" : 'bar-2' },
{ id : 3, "foo-3" : 'bar-3' }
];

ObjectName1.forEach(function(entry1, index) {
    var value = ObjectName2[index][entry1.name];
    console.log(entry1.name + " = " + value);
});
```

That assumes you know they're parallel arrays.

If not, you have to search for it. [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will return the index of the first element where a callback returns true:

```
ObjectName1.forEach(function(entry1) {
    console.log("entry1.name = " + entry1.name);
    var index = ObjectName2.findIndex(function(entry2) {
        // See if entry2 contains a key with that value
        return entry1.name in entry2;
    });
    console.log(index == -1 ? "Not found" : ("Found at index #" + index + ", value = " + ObjectName2[index][entry1.name]));
});
```

Example:

```js
var ObjectName1 = [
{ id : 1, name : 'foo' },
{ id : 2, name : 'foo-2' },
{ id : 3, name : 'foo-3' }
];

var ObjectName2 = [
{ id : 1, "foo" : 'bar' },
{ id : 2, "foo-2" : 'bar-2' },
{ id : 3, "foo-3" : 'bar-3' }
];

ObjectName1.forEach(function(entry1) {
    console.log("entry1.name = " + entry1.name);
    var index = ObjectName2.findIndex(function(entry2) {
        // See if entry2 contains a key with that value
        return entry1.name in entry2;
    });
    console.log(index == -1 ? "Not found" : ("Found at index #" + index + ", value = " + ObjectName2[index][entry1.name]));
});
```

If you don't really need the *key* (e.g., index) of the matching object in `ObjectName2`, just the object, use `find` instead:

```
ObjectName1.forEach(function(entry1) {
    console.log("entry1.name = " + entry1.name);
    var entry = ObjectName2.find(function(entry2) {
        // See if entry2 contains a key with that value
        return entry1.name in entry2;
    });
    console.log(!entry ? "Not found" : ("Found, value is " + entry[entry1.name]));
});
```

Example:

```js
var ObjectName1 = [
{ id : 1, name : 'foo' },
{ id : 2, name : 'foo-2' },
{ id : 3, name : 'foo-3' }
];

var ObjectName2 = [
{ id : 1, "foo" : 'bar' },
{ id : 2, "foo-2" : 'bar-2' },
{ id : 3, "foo-3" : 'bar-3' }
];

ObjectName1.forEach(function(entry1) {
    console.log("entry1.name = " + entry1.name);
    var entry = ObjectName2.find(function(entry2) {
        // See if entry2 contains a key with that value
        return entry1.name in entry2;
    });
    console.log(!entry ? "Not found" : ("Found, value is " + entry[entry1.name]));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer sir, but for now i just need the corrected answer from my question, i think you gave me another option... thanks for trying to help me. your answer is quite clear actually :D

Comment: @DarkCode999: Just to be clear, your accepted answer is my first code snippet above, just with less explanation. (But please don't change your accepted answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var name = ObjectName1[key].name;
ObjectName2.forEach(function(a) {
  if (a.keys().includes(name)) {
    var bar = a[name];
    // then do what you want with bar
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented, your `key` is an object. Hence, it is showing `[Object object].foo-3`.

You will have to use 2 loops and check if the key is inside current object. If yes, print it, else continue.

```js
var ObjectName1 =[
  { id : 1, name : 'foo' },
  { id : 2, name : 'foo-2' },
  { id : 3, name : 'foo-3' },
]

var ObjectName2 = [
  { id : 1, foo : 'bar' },
  { id : 2, 'foo-2' : 'bar-2' },
  { id : 3, 'foo-3' : 'bar-3' },
];

ObjectName1.forEach(function(obj){
  ObjectName2.forEach(function(obj2){
    var key = obj.name;
    if(key in obj2){
      console.log(obj2[key])
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer sir, but the answer below is better :D

Comment: Glad  was able to help!